# Excel Line chart using start and end values as data

Tags: excel, graph, line

So I need to make a line chart, the columns will be split to 9 objectives, and the rows a 1-6 scale. USers are asked to rank themselves between 1 and 6 at the start and end of the course and I wish to show a line for each objective to signify the travel from point A. (start) to point B (end)Somehting like this:

[image: Excel example]

I just can;t seem to make it work! Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the objectives literally "Objective 1", "Objective 2", or are they text like "Lose weight", "Drink less beer" etc.?

Comment: Hi,
Yes, they are objectives 1-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion there are at least three possible approaches to this but each one has it drawbacks:-

(1) Just plot each Line separately as a Line graph and move it to a separate sheet (right-click and select Move Graph). Then you can put the graphs next to each other. The down-side is that it is rather fiddly and you may not want them to appear as separate graphs.

(2) Do the first graph as a Scatter using 1 and 2 as the x-coordinates and your first 2 points as the y-coordinates. Then do the next graph with x-coordinates 2 and 3 and use copy and paste to move it onto the same axes as the first graph (click on the line joining the points and use Ctrl-C and Ctlr-V to copy it onto the first graph). The downside is that each line copied in this way will come out in a different colour and once again it is fiddly to change it.

(3) Do the whole thing as one Scatter graph. You need to re-format the data as below to get some suitable coordinates. To get the break between the lines you need a genuine empty cell (not "" produced by a formula) so I suggest you copy the coordinates in pairs (e.g. F2:G3 to F5:G6) and leave every third pair of cells in the column empty. Then select the whole range F2:G27 and insert a Scatter with straight lines joining the points. Fix the X-axis range from 1 to 9.9 and the y-axis range from 1 to 6 and add axis labels and title as required. The downside of using a Scatter like this is that you only have numbers rather than text along the X-axis but it shouldn't matter in your case where you just need an objective number at each tick mark.

In F2:-

```
=INT((ROWS(F$1:F1)+2)/3)
```

In F3:-

```
=F2+0.9
```

In G2:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$C$10,INT((ROWS(G$1:G1)+1)/3),MOD(ROWS(G$1:G1),3)),"")
```

[image]

[image]